# Android Studio not working properly after installing an older version

Tags: android-studio

I have the latest stable version of Android studio 1.5.1. but since the course i am taking from Udacity(Developing Android applications) uses an older version 0.6.8, i installed the older version.

The latest version worked fine; but the older version is not able to sync projects with Gradle files and also says "No render target selected" when trying to design the fragment_main.xml file.

I have tried many suggestions from stackoverflow like pointing android studio to the SDK directory but they didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you should always strive to use the latest and greatest version of Android Studio. I know that when you get a mismatch between the Gradle plugin version and the Gradle build system version, strange, incomprehensible, errors result. The plugin and the build system represent two different components with completely different versions. Valid combinations of supported version pairs are published on developer.android.com. Take a look at the table [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Gradle-Requirements).